# Min-Maxing / max-value of two slices in a list

Tags: python, list, max, min

I've got a list like `[3,10,4,3,9,15,6,13]` and I want to find two series / sequences that don't over lap and gives the max value obtainable by taking largest-lowest value. They have to be sequential so you can't subtract item 3 from 1. You can however subtract index 1 from 3.

So in my example you would get the pairs [3,10] and [3,15]. How can you do this programmaticly. Heres what I got so far.

python:

```
l = [3,10,4,3,9,15,6,13]
pair1=[max(l), min(l)]
l.remove(max(l))
l.remove(min(l))
pair2=[max(l), min(l)]
```

which of course does not do what I want, but I'm unsure how to proceed in finding two pairs. Finding one pair the above code works fine but not for two as you usually get overlapping sequences.

Comment: so basically you want to find the combination with highest difference in the list amongst all possible combinations?

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for explaining it more briefly.

Comment: Wait... What about two pairs, non-overlapping and ordering of the difference?

Comment: Yeah thats is what I dont understand.

Comment: Ah okei. Eh how to explain I want the highest difference in combinations but the combinations cannot be overlapping. So you can't have a difference where you take `[3,15,1]` So  the combination  `[15,1]` is not valid. As this would be counted as `-14`.

Comment: What should the output be for: `[1,9,11,99]`? `[1,9,2,99]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of fun to write this:

```
import itertools as it

l = [3,10,4,3,9,15,6,13]

r=sorted(
    map(lambda x: (x[0:2], x[2:4]),
        sorted(it.imap(
            lambda x: (min(x[0:2]), max(x[0:2]), min(x[2:4]), max(x[2:4])),
            it.imap(lambda x: (l[x[0]], l[x[1]], l[x[2]], l[x[3]]),
                    it.combinations(range(len(l)), 4))),
               key=lambda x: -(x[1]-x[0]+x[3]-x[2])))[0],
    key=lambda x: x[0]-x[1])

print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it is not so elegant, but try this:

```
l = [3,10,4,3,9,15,6,13]

# list to store diffs
diff=[]
# calculate diffs
for i in range(0, len(l)-1):
    diff.append(l[i+1]-l[i])

# list to store diff sequences
results=[]

# Findinf the sequences
curr=0;
while curr<=(len(diff)-1):

    # list to store positive differences
    result=[]

    # llop while the difference is positive
    while diff[curr]>0 :

        # if it is a first element
        if len(result) == 0:
            # in 0th place store the diff sum
            result.append(diff[curr])
            # in 1st place store the sequence start index 
            result.append(curr)
            # in 2nd place store the sequence end index
            result.append(curr+1)
        else:
            # summ the sequnce diff
            result[0]+=diff[curr]
            # update sequence end index
            result[2]=curr+1
        # move to next element
        curr+=1
        # if reached end of array, break the loop 
        if curr>(len(diff)-1):
            break
    # if there was a sequence store it             
    if (len(result) > 0):
        results.append(result)
    else:
        # move to next element in case of there was no sequence
        curr+=1

# sort the results by sum in reverse order of the 0th element(sum) and normal order of 1st element(start index)
results.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]*10-x[1], reverse=True)
# print first 2 results
for i in range(0,2):
    print "[%d,%d]" % (l[results[i][1]],l[results[i][2]])
```

At least for your input it prints the wanted results :)